# Convert between enums with structs

Tags: rust

I'm trying to design a system that has many different sub-systems, each of which can have multiple possible implementations, and each of these is called by a common code path. Something like this (note that each sub-system can have the same A, B and C implementations):

```
                          /--- ASubSystem1
          /--- SubSystem1 ---- BSubSystem1
         /                \--- CSubSystem1
        /
       /                  /--- ASubSystem2
System ------- SubSystem2 ---- BSubSystem2
       \                  \--- CSubSystem2
        \
         \                /--- ASubSystem3
          \--- SubSystem3 ---- BSubSystem3
                          \--- CSubSystem3
```

To configure the system, I'm creating an enum that stores configuration general to A, B and C, something like this:

```rust
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

pub enum SystemConfig {
  A(AConfig),
  B(BConfig),
  C(CConfig),
}
```

However, when calling each of the sub systems in the common code path, I also want to add some sub-system specific parameters to the call in addition to the Config structs, something like this:

```rust
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

pub enum SubSystem1Params {
  A(ASubSystem1Params),
  B(BSubSystem1Params),
  C(CSubSystem1Params),
}

pub struct ASubSystem1Params {
  config: AConfig,
  ... other params required to call ASubSystem1
}
...
```

What is the best way to convert between these two enums? Both from SystemConfig to SubSystem1Params and from SubSystem1Params to SystemConfig? Is there a cleaner way than having to manually implement (and call) functions like this using matches?

```rust
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

fn to_system_config(sub_system1_params: SubSystem1Params) -> System {
  match sub_system1_params {
    A(a) => a.config,
    B(b) => b.config,
    C(c) => c.config,
  }
}

fn to_sub_system1_params(system_config: SystemConfig) -> SubSystem1Config {
  match system {
    A(a) => SubSystem1Params { config: a, ...other params for a },
    B(b) => SubSystem1Params { config: b, ...other params for b },
    C(c) => SubSystem1Params { config: c, ...other params for c },
  }
}
```

What I *explicitly* want to avoid is something like this:

```rust
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

pub struct SubSystem1CallParams {
  config: SystemConfig,
  params: SubSystem1Params,
}
```

Because there is no way to be sure that config and params have the same enum value - I want to make it impossible (with a compilation failure) to have config be of one type (say A) and params of another type (say B).